# Linux distro with jodin3 preinstalled on live desktop

Tags: linux, hp, samsung

I was thumbing through a couple of distros and found one that had samsung and jodin3 preinstalled and on the Live desktop. Does anyone know what distro this is? I was going to reload it but lost it in the shuffle. Ultimately, I'll be flashing old phones on one computer(as a hobby) and testing android linux hybrids on SSD convertibles with without keyboards/OR/bad touchscreens (for fun). Also old iPads and phones. Any suggestions welcome. Thanks in advance.